# Does Fairy Fencer F: Advent Dark Force contain the same story as Fairy Fencer F?

Tags: version-differences, fairy-fencer-f

I own both *Fairy Fencer F* on the PS3 and *Fairy Fencer F: Advent Dark Force* on the PS4.

i know that Advent Dark Force as improvements to the gameplay from the original game but i want to know if Fairy Fencer F: Advent Dark Force is just a remade version of the original game or if it's a squeal/different story. as the first Hyperdiemsntion Neptunia game for PS3 was remade for PS Vita and PC and while key plot elements remained (releasing Histoire using the Key Fragments, Arfoire's final battle) the same the progression and events were very different ie.

> in Re;Birth Overlord Momus is created when in the original game it never exists. in the original game Neptune regains her Memories after the Legendary Weapons are reassembled (in Re;Birth they weren't split apart, just aged) but tried to abandon the party to fight Arfoire alone (leading to a battle with her). in Re;Birth there is more Shoujo Ai/Yuri love between Vert and IF and the method to travel to Celestia is different

So Does Fairy Fencer F: Advent Dark Force contain the same story as Fairy Fencer F?

Comment: I wasn't sure how to tag Fairy Fencer F: Advent Dark Force (since the entire thing was just too long for a tag name), so I didn't add one to go with the version differences tag.

Answer (score 3):

Advent Dark Force contains 3 story paths, the original story and 2 completely new ones. Which path you get depends on how many swords you removed from the Vile God statue at a certain point.

Exact numbers:

> 6 or less gets the original story, between 7 and 15 gets the "Vile God" route, 16+ gets the "Evil Goddess" route (balanced for New Game+)